# Replacing Mathf.PerlinNoise in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

I was following some tutorials on Youtube trying to make my own voxel engine. The problem is, all tutorials I found uses `Mathf.PerlinNoise(float x, float z)` as the main method from get the noises. So, I have a problem with it, that is simmetry. If x or z are negative, it acts like being positive, and this happen.[image: Simmetric noise]

In other hand, using FastNoiseLite, I ever get a full yellow screen.

The code used to generate the noises are:

```
    public GSC_Noise(int seed)
    {
        Random.InitState(seed);
        gNoise = new FastNoiseLite(seed);
    }


    //From B3AGZ tutorial.
    //GSC_BlockHelper.ChunkSize is a static readonly Vector3Int
    public float Get2DNoise(int x, int z, int offset, float scale)
      => Mathf.PerlinNoise((x + 0.5f) / GSC_BlockHelper.ChunkSize.x * scale + offset,
                           (z + 0.5f) / GSC_BlockHelper.ChunkSize.z * scale + offset);

    public float Get2DNoiseFast(int x, int z, int offset, float scale)
        => gNoise.GetNoise((x + 0.5f) / GSC_BlockHelper.ChunkSize.x * scale + offset,
                           (z + 0.5f) / GSC_BlockHelper.ChunkSize.z * scale + offset);
```

Since FastNoiseLite returns in -1~1 range, against the 0~1 range from Mathf.PerlinNoise, that can be useful in some calculations, I asking for help to know how to set it properly, or other options that don´t cause simmetry on final result;

I am trying to generate a pseudo-random texture based in Perlin Noise. Basically to make randomic continents, like a randomic planet. Other calculations for heights, biomes, etc...

Comment: couldn't you remap the noise such that x and z are not negative?

Comment: Problem of this approach, is that you need to provide a "negative threshold". It´s fine, but if the player pass this threshold, the value need to be extended and all the calculations need to be done again, that means the old map will change in new calculations.

Comment: hmmm... how about layering two perlin noises over eachother, with an offset?

Comment: Works perfectly... I don´t think on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As pixlHero suggests in comment, I use two noises interpolated and the results are:[image]

So, for others with same doubt, I let the this question for help them.